# Create gist index on cube array with 512 dimensions

Tags: postgresql, gist-index

I want to perform nearest neighbors search on db with 5000 entries of cube array with 512 dimensions.

I referred to this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/163915/revisions) and used docker image of postgresql with cube array limit set to 2048 which can be found in the comment to the answer. But I'm getting the following error:

`ERROR:  failed to add item to index page in "faq_c_idx"
SQL state: XX000`

It works with dimensions=~200, but when I set higher dimensions I keep receiving the error above.

Here's the query:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
AS
  SELECT i, cube(array_agg(random()::float)) AS c
  FROM generate_series(1,5000) AS i
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,512)
    AS x
  GROUP BY i;

CREATE INDEX ON mytable USING gist ( c );
ANALYZE mytable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find a place to store the index tuple, probably because the tuple is larger than a page and so can't fit on any page.  You could recompile with a larger blocksize, e.g. `./configure --with-blocksize=32`, but then you will just run into a different limitation, probably INDEX_SIZE_MASK, which is not so easy to work around.

So, you just can't do this.  But if you could, an index into a 512 dimensional cube is not likely to be all that useful anyway.  It will probably be slower than a seq-scan would be, or at least not faster by very much.